# mywindow.print() not showing the content

Tags: javascript, html

I inserted a button in my page and when I click on this button, I run a javascript to create a window and print it. The only thing I do is remove the button from the HTML content.

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
       <br>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value=" Print Application " onClick="printApp();" />
       ....
       <!-- All my HTML content goes here -->
   </div>
   <script>
        function printApp(){
            var content = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
            content = content.replace('<input type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-success\" value=\" Print Application \" onclick=\"printApp();\">', '');                          
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=600,width=800');

            mywindow.document.write(content);
            mywindow.document.close();
            mywindow.focus()
            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();
            return true;                     
        }                               
    </script>
</body>
```

When the print page opens, it does not display the content. However, if I run the script code in the browser console, it works.

Comment: Your code works for me.   I created an HTML file with this code and add a content, opened in a browser and the print page shows correctly the content.

Comment: It's odd, not working for me

Comment: Also, it is not working for safari. The print window opens and closes with Safari